# JIRA JQL: coloring cards by blocked status

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql, scriptrunner-for-jira

I'm trying to use the "Card colors" feature of JIRA Agile, plus the ScriptRunner plugin, to color blocked cards on a JIRA agile board.

My definition of "blocked" is: ticket has a value for the "Blocked" field or is linked to an unresolved ticket in a "is blocked by" relationship.

The best I can do is the following JQL:

`(Blocked is not EMPTY) OR issueFunction in hasLinks("is blocked by")`

This finds tickets that have a value for the "Blocked" field, and tickets that are linked to another ticket in a "is blocked by" relationship, but it will still color the card if all linked blockers are resolved.

Is there any way to only find tickets linked to unresolved blockers?

I looked in the [ScriptRunner docs](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this the other way around: Find all linked issues that are marked as being a blocker and have no resolution set.

Example to find all unresolved tickets with unresolved blockers:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("resolution is EMPTY", "blocks") and resolution is EMPTY
```

Comment: Update: I changed the JQL slightly to also trigger when the "Blocked" field has a value:

`Blocked is not empty OR (issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("resolution is EMPTY", "blocks") and resolution is EMPTY)`

Comment: FYI, this solution requires a paid subscription for the ScriptRunner plugin. It's insane that Jira does not have the ability to search for these issues with native JQL.

Comment: Isn't it possible to install the latest unpaid version? IIRC it had that, too.