# Change a card color in JIRA Cloud for blockers

Tags: jira

Again, I do not have enough of a reputation to respond to the post string already out there, so I am creating a new post.  Apologies for the duplication.

I'm trying to do the same thing as this post: [JIRA JQL: coloring cards by blocked status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192259/jira-jql-coloring-cards-by-blocked-status)

However I have JIRA cloud, which means I am limited on what ScriptRunner does as well.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to do this as well for a few weeks. So far I have not found a way to accomplish this using JQL. The capabilities of JQL just seem too limited. Honestly this is very disappointing to me as there is hardly any point in blocker links if you cant use them in any meaningful way for quick visual indicators.

Ideally a blocked issue should get some sort of lock icon added and blockers should get a key or something.

Summary: JQL does not seem capable of accomplishing this.

Comment: This is an incredible oversight by Jira.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially possible to implement for JIRA Cloud using (paid) Jql Search Extensions for JIRA plugin:

- Red (blocked): `linkType = "is blocked by" AND linkedIssueStatusCategory in ("To Do","In Progress")`
- Blue (blocker): `linkType = blocks AND linkedIssueStatusCategory in ("To Do","In Progress")`
- Green (unblocked): `linkType = "is blocked by" AND linkedIssueStatusCategory not in ("To Do","In Progress")`

But this plugin's limitation is we can't check `linkedIssueStatusCategory` only for issues of some `linkType` - instead check applies to all linked issues. This means some cards which have links of more than one type will have wrong colour. For example:

- if issue has 1 "is blocked by" link to "Done" issue and 1 "blocks" link to "To Do" issue - it'll have Red colour instead of Blue
- if issue has 1 "is blocked by" link to "Done" issue and 1 "relates" link to "To Do" issue - it'll have Red colour instead of no colour

If it's better to see possibly-not-blocked issues as not Red, then we can use this instead:

- Red (guaranteed to be blocked): `linkType = "is blocked by" AND linkedIssueStatusCategory != Done`